# VMWare, Cannot ping Linux guest from Windows 10 host over bridged connection

Tags: networking, vmware, ping

I'm running VMWare player 16 on a Windows 10 machine. I have a VM running Ubuntu and using a bridged connection on WiFi adapter. I can ping the Ubuntu guest from other PCs in the network but I cannot ping it from the Windows 10 host machine.

Answer (score 0):

In the past I got a problem like this and I didn't find a suitable answer in the internet or VMWare support. At the end the problem was related to a filter that was enabled on the WiFi adapter. The filter was named "LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver", after disabling it in the network adapter properties of the windows host, the ping to the guest started to work again.

Comment: That is the problem for me too. I don't know which software enabled this "LiveQoS NDIS 6 Filter Driver" but it drove me crazy for more than a week. Thank you.

Comment: Please upvote then!